# setTimeout and render cycle

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webkit, rendering

I am curious about what actually happens behind the scenes when using javascript setTimeout.

Example code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   // some sync js code #1 ...

   // some code that will trigger a render (change in the DOM) #1
});
setTimeout(function(){
   // some sync js code #2 ...

   // some code that will trigger a render (change in the DOM) #2
});
```

What I guess would happen is something like:

- entering setTimeout #1
- sync code #1
- registering paint event #1
- exiting setTimeout #1
- rendering / painting paint event #1
- entering setTimeout #2
- sync code #2
- registering paint event #2
- exiting setTimeout #2
- rendering / painting paint event #2

I am aware that in Chrome the painting can either happen in the main thread or be delegated to a worker thread.
I don't know about other browsers.

So, is my hunch correct?

- Does the browser always executes the pending rendering/painting between each setTimeout cycle?
- If not, in which cases not?
- Are there differences between browsers? (Chrome, Firefox, IE...)

Comment: From what I've seen, it always repaints or at least updates the calculated style, because I've been using settimeouts of 0 ms to force computed style updates and my application works on the standard up to date Chrome, Firefox and IE11. A reliable source would be nice though.